# AIDE "atime in future" Warnings

Tags: linux, timestamp

I am on a Debian 10 virtualbox guest test sever and I am trying to configure AIDE.  However, I keep receiving a warning message saying:

```
root@tester1:~# aide -c /etc/aide/aide.conf --check
/ atime in future
/dev atime in future
/dev mtime in future
[...]
```

And sure enough, when I run `stat -c %x /`  , I get  `2021-04-30 18:52:05.616000000 +0800`  which is about ~7+ hours ahead of my current time.

I used lynis and verified that NTP time servers are working correctly. Seems like common problem.  However, I have not been able to find any definitive source / means as to fix this problem.

Any tips?
thx

Answer (score 0):

The cause of my problem was that even though ntp was installed, it [ntp] wasn't actually working as it should've, which I only discovered after running `ntpq -p`.  After adding servers for my current timezone everything worked as it should.